# How to handle JSON's undefined value in a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, json

I'm working on Google Book API to post a book's basic information. I notice that some of the books will always miss a value or two under `volumeInfo`, like this book **([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KU7Zx/21/))** that has no publisher value. Do I need to repeat `if [object] undefined` statement several times for the missing values (e.g Publisher,Average Rating,Rating Count)? Can I do it in a more concise way?

```
 $.ajax({

    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fbooks%2Fv1%2Fvolumes%3Fq%3Disbn%3A1879505215%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

 $(data.query.results.json.items).each(function (index, item) {

    var isbn10;

 $.each(item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, function(index, item) {

    if (item.type === "ISBN_10") {
    isbn10 = item.identifier;
    return false;
    }

    });
    var Rating = item.volumeInfo.averageRating;
    var RatingCount = item.volumeInfo.ratingsCount;
    var item_html = '';          

    item_html += '   
        <li><img src="' +item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail+'</li>
        <li><span>Author:</span> ' + item.volumeInfo.authors + '</li>
        <li><span>Publisher</span> ' + item.volumeInfo.publisher + '</li>
        <li><span>PublishDate:</span> '+item.volumeInfo.publishedDate+'</li>
        <li><span>Category:</span> ' + item.volumeInfo.categories + '</li>
        <li><span>Page Count:</span> ' + item.volumeInfo.pageCount +' </li>
        <li><span>ISBN:</span> ISBN10_' + isbn10 +' </li>
        <li><span>Description: </span> ' + item.volumeInfo.description +' </li>';

    if (Rating != undefined) {
    item_html += '<li><span>Average Rating:' + Rating +'</span></li>';
    }

    if (RatingCount != undefined) {
    item_html += '<li><span>Rating Count:' + RatingCount +'</span></li>';
    }

    var title_html ='' +item.volumeInfo.title + '';

    $('#bookhead').append(title_html);

    $('#bookdetail ul').append(item_html);

    });

    },
    error: function () {}

    });
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. In it's current form it's unreadable.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo edited. I hope it's better now.

Comment: Not really. The indentation should reflect the structure of your code - which statements are nested inside which statement. Just indenting all lines by the same amount is not much help. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841450/proper-indentation-in-javascript

Comment: Also, don't use line breaks inside strings. That's not supported cross-browser and not part of the ECMAScript spec.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a hash of the possible field names and loop through them:

```
var fieldTitles = {
    description: "Description",
    Rating: "Average Rating",
    RatingCount: "Rating Count"
};

var volumeInfo = item.volumeInfo;
for (var key in fieldTitles) {
    if (volumeInfo[key]) {
        item_html += '<li><span>' + fieldTitles[key] + ':' + volumeInfo[key] +'</span></li>';
    }
}
```

Additional notes:

- store `item.volumeInfo` to a local variable so you don't have to access it through `item` object all the time.
- Most of the time it's better and simpler to check for existence of a value with `if (someVar)` rather than comparing directly with undefined.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few way to approach this:

- You can use the `||` shortcut

  ```
  <li><span>Publisher</span> ' + ( item.volumeInfo.publisher || '' )+ '</li>'
  ```
- You could default all the values prior to building your HTML

  ```
  item.volumeInfo.publisher = item.volumeInfo.publisher || 'Publisher unknown';
  ```

Other than that;

- You should use a shortcut for `item.volumeInfo`, like `info`:

  ```
  item_html += '   
      <li><img src="' + info.imageLinks.thumbnail+'</li>
      <li><span>Author:</span> ' + info.authors + '</li>
      <li><span>Publisher</span> ' + info.publisher + '</li>
      <li><span>PublishDate:</span> '+ info.publishedDate+'</li>
      <li><span>Category:</span> ' + info.categories + '</li>
      <li><span>Page Count:</span> ' + info.pageCount +' </li>
      <li><span>ISBN:</span> ISBN10_' + isbn10 +' </li>
      <li><span>Description: </span> ' + info.description +' </li>';
  ```
- Your `success` function should have been separate from the `$.ajax({` call for easier reading
- Indent better, it's a mess
- `var Rating =` -> `var rating =`. Only constructor functions should start with an uppercase letter